# android getter method returns null value

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I use following method to get var from another class. However, firstView receives always null value. Why? Thanks

Main class

```
private String view1 = null;

//...when onCreate view1 is checked that set properly

public String getView1() {

     return view1;   
 }
```

second class

```
TabBar_Activity mainRef = new TabBar_Activity();

firstView = mainRef.getView1();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right behavior because when you getView using `getView1()` method you are creating new `mainRef` object of `TabBar_Activity`. And in that you have just declared `String view1 = null`. **If you want to get setter view1 value then use the object which you are using for setter view1 value in `onCreate()` of activity not new object**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really setting `view1` in that activity's `onCreate()`, then the `onCreate()` of your first activity hasn't been called. Where are you getting the instance of the first activity, whose `getView1()` method you are calling?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you set the value "view1"
Because with the code now it is pretty logical you get a null value